# How to store images and audio? use sql or nosql?

Tags: database, image, audio

I want to store some images and audio from users. But How can i do this.
use sql database such like mysql and postgres, or use nosql like mongo and cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BLOB field type or store images/audio on disk and for every user add a field, which a path to image/video file is in.